# Python - persistent mysql connection in processes

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I have thousands of MySQL queries to run in a python program I am working on. I want to run these concurrently for obvious reasons, and I am trying to work out the best way to do so.

Using multiprocessing, I want to start 8 child processes. Each one should create a connection to SQL which persists for its entire lifetime. Then I want to use a ProcessPool to imap queries into those processes which utilise the persistent SQL connection. Once all queries have returned results, I want to close the connection on each of the processes.

At the moment, I can send an initializer to each of the processes that creates a MySQLdb connection and then use that in each of the queries passed in my imap. However, I can't see a nice way to "de-initialize"/deconstruct the processes and close the DB connection.

Is there a way to close the DB connection when the pool is about to destroy each process?

I've looked at using queues to transfer data to/from, and then subclass multiprocessing.Process and override run, which can create the connection, loop over the queue, and then close the connection in that single call, but there's a little more overhead in reading the queue back out and working out when the queue has nothing else to give which I'm trying to avoid.